# rosinstall openni_kinect error

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when I do

```
rosinstall ~/openni_kinect /opt/ros/electric 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall'
```

I get the following error message:

```
rosinstall ~/openni_kinect /opt/ros/electric 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall'
Is not a local file, nor able to download as a URL[http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall]: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer couldn't load config uri 
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall
ERROR: Bad remote rosinstall source: 
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=openni_kinect.rosinstall  This can be caused by empty or malformed remote rosinstall 
file.
```

Is it the link? or the remote rosinstall file have problems ?

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28870/rosinstall-openni_kinect-error/) by [dcastro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1880/dcastro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki hasn't been super reliable over the past few days. Try again and see if it works. You could also try downloading the rosinstall file separately, and using rosinstall with the local file.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2